# Does Docker override files?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have created simple image based on `mongo:latest`. My Dockerfile is just

```
FROM mongo:3.3
MAINTAINER developer@encode.cz
```

Now when I run it by cmd `docker run my-mongo mongod` I get no `/data/db` error. But there is clearly `RUN mkdir /data/db` in mongo base image. Also pure mongo base image works as expected.

Why is this folder not present in my custom image if it is in the base image?

Comment: Do you give `/data/db`right owner and permissions?

Comment: I have run my image with -ti args and didn´t even see /data folder. But expected it to be at-least created by previous image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problems in the way you are testing or I don't understand well your question. I tested the official image:

```
docker run -d --name mongo mongo:3.3 mongod
docker exec -it mongo bash -c 'ls -la /data/db'

total 192
drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 18:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root     4096 Oct 21 20:47 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    46 Oct 28 17:56 WiredTiger
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    21 Oct 28 17:56 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb   935 Oct 28 18:11 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 40960 Oct 28 18:11 WiredTiger.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 17:56 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 17:57 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 17:57 collection-0--3585910680230311914.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 17:57 collection-2--3585910680230311914.wt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 18:11 diagnostic.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 17:57 index-1--3585910680230311914.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 17:57 index-3--3585910680230311914.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 17:57 index-4--3585910680230311914.wt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 17:56 journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb     2 Oct 28 17:56 mongod.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 17:57 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    95 Oct 28 17:56 storage.bson
```

Then I created a Dockerfile with your two lines and:

```
docker build -t my-mongo .
docker run -d --name my-mongo my-mongo mongod
docker exec -it my-mongo bash -c 'ls -la /data/db'

total 192
drwxr-xr-x 4 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 18:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root     4096 Oct 21 20:47 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    46 Oct 28 18:06 WiredTiger
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    21 Oct 28 18:06 WiredTiger.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb   932 Oct 28 18:12 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 40960 Oct 28 18:12 WiredTiger.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 18:06 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 18:07 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 18:07 collection-0-683121925029568227.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 18:07 collection-2-683121925029568227.wt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 18:13 diagnostic.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 18:07 index-1-683121925029568227.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 18:07 index-3-683121925029568227.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 18:07 index-4-683121925029568227.wt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Oct 28 18:06 journal
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb     2 Oct 28 18:06 mongod.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 16384 Oct 28 18:07 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    95 Oct 28 18:06 storage.bson
```

Be aware, the /data/db directory is declared as a volume. If you are having problems withn that, restart the docker daemon and check your available disk space `df -h`

Regards

Comment: I just did the same. The first step is exactly same as yours, everything works fine. I have even tried 'docker inspect mongo' to see volume mounting source. But when I run my-mongo image created as before, I get "Container not running..." due to same error -  /data/db is not created.

Comment: Well 1 suggestion: test in another machine. 2 restart the docker daemon. 3 check your docker version

Comment: Yep, I reinstalled version 1.12.1 to 1.12.1, rebuild image and now its OK. I dont get it, 2 pointless hours wasted for nothing. I would even understand it if I had done some modifications to docker setting, but it was fresh install and my first experience with docker :(.